# Slugify and Character Transliteration in C#

Tags: c#, internationalization, slug, transliteration

I'm trying to translate the following slugify method from PHP to C#: 
http://snipplr.com/view/22741/slugify-a-string-in-php/

***Edit:*** For the sake of convenience, here the code from above:

```
/**
 * Modifies a string to remove al non ASCII characters and spaces.
 */
static public function slugify($text)
{
    // replace non letter or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

    // trim
    $text = trim($text, '-');

    // transliterate
    if (function_exists('iconv'))
    {
        $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    }

    // lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);

    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

    if (empty($text))
    {
        return 'n-a';
    }

    return $text;
}
```

I got no probleming coding the rest except I can not find the C# equivalent of the following line of PHP code:

```
$text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
```

***Edit:***
Purpose of this is to translate non-ASCII characters such as `Reformáció Genfi Emlékműve Előtt` into `reformacio-genfi-emlekmuve-elott`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would also like to add that the `//TRANSLIT` removes the apostrophes and that @jxac solution doesn't address that. I'm not sure why but by first encoding it to Cyrillic and then to ASCII you get a similar behavior as `//TRANSLIT`.

```
var str = "éåäöíØ";
var noApostrophes = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes(str)); 

=> "eaaoiO"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution!  I have been looking for a way to replace non-US-ASCII characters with an ASCII equivalent for an old mainframe system that can't handle these characters.

Comment: This just removes accents and does not do actual transliteration. It will loose all non-accented letters in the process.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by actual transliteration but it sure does not drop the non-accented letters. `Reformáció Genfi Emlékműve Előtt` => `Reformacio Genfi Emlekmuve Elott`

Comment: "Привет" however becomes just an empty string. Which is what I said, it drops non-accented non-latin letters. In your example it only removed accents and the rest of the letters are already latin, so no transliteration takes place.

Comment: Testing this in .Net 4.6.1 it seems to work well with Nordic characters `åäöæø`, russian  and japanease/chinease chars becomes questionmarks ? and it keeps slashes which you cannot use in a slug, so you would need to replace/remove questionmarks and slashes and other invalid url chars and it will depend on what languages you need..

Answer (score 9):

There is a .NET library for transliteration on codeplex - [unidecode](http://unidecode.codeplex.com/). It generally does the trick using Unidecode tables ported from python.

Answer (score 1):

conversion to string:

```
byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII, unicodeBytes);
string asciiString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiBytes);
```

conversion to bytes:

```
byte[] ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
```

[@Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173825/slugify-and-character-transliteration-in-c/2173883#217388) is right, will get encoded by the output stream...

to remove the diacritics (accent marks), you can use the String.Normalize function, as detailed here:

http://www.siao2.com/2007/05/14/2629747.aspx

that should take care of most of the cases (where the glyph is really a character plus an accent mark). for an even more aggressive char matching (to take care of cases like the Scandinavian [slashed o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98) [Ø], digraphs, and other exotic glyphs), there's the table approach:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UnicodeNormalization.aspx

this includes around 1,000 symbol mappings in addition to the normalization.

(note, all punctuation is removed by the regex replace in your example)