# How do you remove invalid characters when creating a friendly url (ie how do you create a slug)?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, slug

Say I have this webpage:
http://ww.xyz.com/Product.aspx?CategoryId=1

If the name of CategoryId=1 is "Dogs" I would like to convert the URL into something like this:
http://ww.xyz.com/Products/Dogs

The problem is if the category name contains foreign (or invalid for a url) characters. If the name of CategoryId=2 is "Göra äldre", what should be the new url?

Logically it should be:
[http://ww.xyz.com/Products/Göra](http://ww.xyz.com/Products/G%C3%B6ra) äldre
but it will not work. Firstly because of the space (which I can easily replace by a dash for example) but what about the foreign characters? In Asp.net I could use the URLEncode function which would give something like this:
http://ww.xyz.com/Products/G%c3%b6ra+%c3%a4ldre
but I can't really say it's better than the original url (http://ww.xyz.com/Product.aspx?CategoryId=2)

Ideally I would like to generate this one but how can I can do this automatically (ie converting foreign characters to 'safe' url characters):
http://ww.xyz.com/Products/Gora-aldre

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've come up with the 2 following extension methods (asp.net / C#):

```
     public static string RemoveAccent(this string txt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes(txt);
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    }

    public static string Slugify(this string phrase)
    {
        string str = phrase.RemoveAccent().ToLower();
        str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, @"[^a-z0-9\s-]", ""); // Remove all non valid chars          
        str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ").Trim(); // convert multiple spaces into one space  
        str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "-"); // //Replace spaces by dashes
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: I wrote out a huge method full of if statements using the char class until I found this. Good stuff.

Comment: I think ISAPI  does the same, but I want more control over my URLs. This is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the function. I had to add another piece at the end to replace two or more hyphens with a single hyphen.
    str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, @"\-+", "- "); // convert multiple hyphens into one hyphen

Comment: I used this beautiful solution but I kept accents and replaced [^a-z0-9\s-] with this [^\w\d\s-] to support Unicode URL's. Up vote this or hug me.

Answer (score 3):

One other thing worth considering:

If a user provides a string such as `好听的音乐` which you want to convert to a URL friendly title then you should consider using [IdnMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.idnmapping(v=vs.110).aspx)

For example:

```
string urlFriendlyTitle = Slugify(url);

public static string Slugify(string text)
{
    IdnMapping idnMapping = new IdnMapping();
    text = idnMapping.GetAscii(text);

    text = RemoveAccent(text).ToLower();

    //  Remove all invalid characters.  
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^a-z0-9\s-]", "");

    //  Convert multiple spaces into one space
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", " ").Trim();

    //  Replace spaces by underscores.
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s", "_");

    return text;
}

public static string RemoveAccent(string text)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes(text);

    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Without this, `好听的音乐` will be converted to `string.Empty`. With this, `xn--fjqr6lw2ek78az68a` which is [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)

Answer (score 2):

Transliterate non-ASCII characters to ASCII, using something like this:

```
var str = "éåäöíØ";
var noApostrophes = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes(str)); 

=> "eaaoiO"
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173825/slugify-and-character-transliteration-in-c))

Comment: What if some characters are not Cyrillic? I need a solution which will always work.

Comment: Then you'll need to add more checks for different types of encoding. Unfortunately there's no magic wand here unless you use a library that does it all for you.

Comment: Maybe the UnidecodeSharp library is what you are looking for: http://unidecode.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -1):

I use the function described at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/converting-text-to-a-url-friendly-slug. It doesn't directly support non-English characters, but could be easily updated to support additional characters.

I like it because it produces a very clean-looking slug.

Comment: In your TextToSlug function what if the string to convert contains an accent? For example 'fiancé' which is a perfect English word. There are plenty of similar examples in English. IsLetterOrDigit will return true for the é character so you would end up with it in your url which would be incorrect as ideally é should be converted to e in the url.

Comment: What does "ideally" mean here? Are you saying fiancé is invalid within a URL? This hasn't come while I've been using my code, but I'm more than happy to modify it if this causes problems.